# Wireless packet sniffer for windows

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a wifi connection whose password I know and I want to sniff all the data packets on this network with my computer. What is the best tool for this purpose on windows? I am lookinf for something free but functionality like http://www.inssider.com/ or Commview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish:

1.) hacking/cracking your WiFi:

If you have a thumbdrive or spare CD-R laying around, you can check out [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux), it's a 'hackers toolkit' that includes tons of forensic tools that can be used to analyze 'your' WiFi. It can be burned to a CD/thumbdrive and used in a 'Live' version. Support for WiFi cards is 'sort' of limited for some 'air capture' drivers but a lot of that depends on your WiFi card as well. Kali is a Debian derivative so most Debian packages will work with it (like WiFi drivers built for Debian)

2.) Sniffing your internal network:

Check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org), this just gives you a packet dump of what's traversing your internal network (WiFi and Wired)

Mind you both of these avenues are 'IP/software' based; 1 allows you to see how 'open' your WiFi is (i.e. is your SSID easily viewable/attainable and do you have 'safe' encryption like using AES in WPA-PSK2 mode vs. just using WEP); if you follow some '[basic WiFi security](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=basic%20wifi%20security)' tips, you will be as 'safe' as you can be.

The second option just lets you 'see' what traffic is going across the network you specify (WiFi cards can have issues with this as they have to be put into promiscuous mode, so keep that in mind if you have a cheap WiFi card).

I know you said free [software], but just for some extra info, there are devices you can buy that will capture the raw WiFi data that's actually going over the air. [Fluke](http://www.flukenetworks.com) makes some WiFi devices and there's also the (in)famous [AirPcap](http://www.riverbed.com/products-solutions/products/network-performance-management/wireshark-enhancement-products/Wireless-Traffic-Packet-Capture.html) device as well.

Hope that can help

Comment: I have a small embedded wifi device . I am trying to see if it is actually sending out wifi packets. I have a scope and I want to confirm the packets are actuallly getting transmitted through the physical hardware. Is there any cheaper hardware device that will sniff packets? $200 is expensive for the sniffer

Comment: Also is there any specific wifi dongle card which can definitely operate in promiscous mode with Kali?

Comment: @Sab You could setup a device as a WiFi hotspot and then sniff for data off the wifi interface of the WiFi hotspot.

Comment: @Sab, unfortunately no, physical WiFi sniffers are expensive because of the hardware they employ more than the software that is needed to drive them (that's the subject for another topic though) so there's not much you can do on that front. [Here's](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/8504/supported-adapters-for-wireless-packet-capturing) a good thread on WiFi cards/adapters for promisc mode, I've got an Intel wifi chipset in mine and am able to capture all.

Comment: Also, like @Lawrence said, you could setup another box for the embedded device to directly connect via WiFi to another PC (think AdHoc or WiFi ICS). Then on the WiFi device you could just see if anything is being sent over that link via Wireshark/Kali/etc.